# Cannot find library using gcc -shared in Eclipse to build a dll

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, mingw

I am trying to use the FFMPEG library that I just compiled on Windows using MinGW in a C program in Eclipse. I have managed to build a simple HelloJNI.c file and run it:

```
gcc $(INCLUDES) -c -g -w HelloJNI.c
gcc -shared -o $(BIN_DIR)/hello.dll HelloJNI.o
```

I am now trying to compile a ffmpeg_native.c file that uses FFMPEG but I am getting errors running the following:

```
LIBRARY_PATH = -L:"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local/lib" -L:"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local"
INCLUDES = -I$(SRC_DIR) -I"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local/include" -I"c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45/include" -I"c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45//include/win32"
BIN_DIR = ../bin

gcc $(INCLUDES) -c -g -w ffmpeg_native1.1.4.c
gcc -shared -o $(BIN_DIR)/exportnative.dll ffmpeg_native1.1.4.o $(LIBRARY_PATH) -lffmpeg -lavcodec -lx264 -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale
```

The first line runs fine but the second shows this output:

```
c:/Dev/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lavcodec
[etc for all libraries]
```

I am puzzled as I am able to run the following in MinGW with success:

```
ld -o /local/libffmpeg.so -L/local/lib -lavcodec -lx264 -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot find library path since `-L` is missing before `$(LIBRARY_PATH)`. From gcc man:

> -L*dir*
>  Add directory *dir* to the list of directories to be searched for `-l`.

So, if `LIBRARY_PATH` contains directory with needed libraries and everyting other is fine the following should work:

```
gcc -shared -o $(BIN_DIR)/exportnative.dll ffmpeg_native1.1.4.o -L$(LIBRARY_PATH) -lffmpeg -lavcodec -lx264 -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale
```

---

It is not needed to put colon `:` between `-L` and the path. The following list should be added to the command line:

```
-L"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local/lib" -L"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local"`
```

---

Note that it is better to use some other environment variable name for building the command line, since `LIBRARY_PATH` is used by gcc directly:

> `LIBRARY_PATH`
>   The value of `LIBRARY_PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories,
>   much like `PATH`. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the
>   directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if
>   it can't find them using `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`. Linking using GCC also uses
>   these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the `-l`
>   option (but directories specified with `-L` come first).

Comment: Sorry should have specified what LIBRARY_PATH is. -L is already included. Amended the question.

Comment: @tishu you should not put colon `:` between and `-L` and the path. It should be `-L"c:/Dev/msys-1.0/local/lib"`.